# Chart.js change label font color

Tags: javascript, charts

I have a simple chart using http://www.chartjs.org like :

```
<script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart2');
        var data = {
            labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "My First dataset",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,0.2)",
                borderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
                pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
                data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40]
            }, {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
                borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
                pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
                data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
            }]
        };
        var option = {
            showLines: false
        };
        var myLineChart = Chart.Radar(canvas, {
            data: data,
            options: option
        });
    </script>
```

I'm looking for in the documentation but I don't find how to change all labels color ?

In my exemple I need to change color of `labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running"]` or `label: "My First dataset",`

Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe check out `defaultFontColor` http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-global-configuration

Answer (score 8):

```
/*Global settings*/
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#fff';
```

Comment: This goes where exactly?

Comment: This is set on the global Chart. Just put it anywhere.

Comment: please mention where exactly this can be done ? especially in typescript in Angular 2 / 4. I tried but nothing worked - it indeed gave compilation errors.

Comment: This sometimes automatically refreshes the graph (chart) and sometimes not. I do not know how to implement the change correctly. So, this answer is partially true.

Comment: I'm using angular-chart.js and the `fontColor: "#fff"` wasn't working for me, really don't know why, but this line of code did it, thanks a lot..

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is using ng2-charts with Typescript:

in the Component:

```
private lineChartOptions:any = {
    legend : {
        labels : {
          fontColor : '#ffffff'  
        }
    }
};
```

In the template:

```
<canvas baseChart [options]="lineChartOptions"></canvas>
```

Comment: This Setting helps only changing the Legend Labels Color not all the labels in the charts - which is by default color : #666

Comment: How to change the x-axis and y axis color in this way @stefan?